# My if/else/elif statement is not working in Python

Tags: python

I wanted to make a menu for a restaurant. Because I am new, I wanted to make not a lot of choices so I got a random excuse but that's not my problem right now.
I just need help as when I do my if/else/elif statement, well either I don't know how to use it or I just have a mistake in my code pls help... so this is what I have so far:

```
import sys

def _menu_():
    print('|--------------------------------|')
    print('|Kids menu:                      |')
    print('| Chicken nuggets(G)           3$|')
    print('| Medium size MAC(G)           5$|')
    print('| EXTRA Fries (GF)         +1.50$|')
    print('|*all menu comes with fries*     |')
    print('|G = GLUTEN   GF = GLUTENFREE    |')
    print('|--------------------------------|')

def _menu_COTD():
    print('|--------------------------------|')
    print('|CATCH OF THE DAY:               |')
    print('| Beef tenderloin (grilled)   24$|')
    print('| Grilled salmon,tuna/mayo 12$   |')
    print('| G = GLUTEN   GF = GLUTENFREE   |')
    print('|--------------------------------|')

def _menu_BOTH():
    print('|--------------------------------|')
    print('|Kids menu:                      |')
    print('| Chicken nuggets(G)           3$|')
    print('| Medium size MAC(G)           5$|')
    print('| EXTRA Fries (GF)         +1.50$|')
    print('|*all menu comes with fries*     |')
    print('|G = GLUTEN   GF = GLUTENFREE    |')
    print('|--------------------------------|')
    print('                                  ')
    print('                                  ')
    print('|--------------------------------|')
    print('|CATCH OF THE DAY:               |')
    print('| Beef tenderloin (grilled)   24$|')
    print('| Grilled salmon,tuna/mayo    12$|')
    print('| G = GLUTEN   GF = GLUTENFREE   |')
    print('|--------------------------------|')
    
    



    
print('Owner:')
print ('hello, i am the owner of the restaurant, unfortunately we have been robbed and all our food is gone except for our catch of the day and our kids menu')
print('    ')
print('is it ok or you want to go to another restaurant (knowing that our prices reduced by 75%)')
print('write "yes" if you want to eat here and write "no" to go somewhere else')

menu_choice = input('will you stay?')
if menu_choice == 'yes':
    print('ok great so what will you take?')

    
else:
    print('ok then, enjoy you expensive other restaurant')
    sys.exit()

menu_choice_2 = input('Kids menu, Catch of the day, or both?')

if menu_choice_2 == 'kids menu':
    _menu_
    
if: menu_choice_2 == 'Catch of th day':
    _menu_COTD
    
if: menu_choice_2 == 'Both':
    _menu_BOTH
```

so when it says `menu_choice_2`I basically want to have either `_menu_` (the kids menu) `_menu_COTD` (the catch of the day) and `_menu_BOTH` (which is both, `_menu_` and `_menu_COTD`. Pls, help. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: `_menu_` (for example) is simply stating the name of the function - you haven't told Python to actually *do* anything with the function.  Try `_menu_()` to actually call the function.

Comment: The last two if statements have errors, there are colons right after the `if` and not after the entire statement

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't start function names with underscores (i.e. `_`). (There's an exception for "private" class methods and module functions, but that doesn't seem to apply here.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors.

- First, there are unnecessary colon(:) for the last two if statement.
- Second, you need a parenthesis to call the function (e.g., *menu*())

I just fixed the last part of the code, so that you can call the functions:

```
if menu_choice_2 == 'kids menu':
    _menu_()

if menu_choice_2 == 'Catch of th day':
    _menu_COTD()

if menu_choice_2 == 'Both':
    _menu_BOTH()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to call your function. Right now when you write *menu*, it evaluates to nothing. Instead, write `_menu_()` and same for other functions too.
Also you have a typo in your last if statements, remove the colons from in front of `if` statements